# Draenor: does any in-game text make the connection to Outland?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

The continent Draenor is identical to what became Outland at some point or in another time line. Many third-party magazines have stated this, and it is fairly obvious looking at the names of various zones and places.

However, has this connection (*edit:* the fact that this must be the **past** of Outland, or an alternate timeline) ever been referenced on screen (*edit:* in Warlords of Draenor)? For example, a non-player character saying something like "Looks like something has changed the time line" or "This must be how Outland has looked like in the past".

I have levelled up to 100, completed the garrison campaign up to the point of reaching Tanaan Jungle, and I can't remember anything like this. A friend says he's sure to have seen it, but can't remember details. Can you?

## Update

Before WoD, it was of course known that the name of the planet that became Outland was "Draenor". One could assume that the player makes the connection based on this, but I would have expected Blizzard to let at least one NPC (or readable in-world item) inside Warlords of Draenor content actually state the connection and timeline difference.

Comment: ...I would expect the quest that sends you to Draenor would tell you this.

Comment: Not aware of specific texts, but Lantresor of the Blade is much younger in Draenor than in Outland. This is a pretty good evidence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Emphasis added.)

The most direct acknowledgments are from the quest [Fugitive Dragon](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=36000/fugitive-dragon):

> A bronze dragon freed Garrosh Hellscream and took him to this world. His name is Kairozdormu, and he's a fugitive from Azeroth. It's time to track him down.
>
> His essence permeates **this entire timeline**. If I could just get a hold of him - dead or alive! - I could re-calibrate my magic to **this era of Draenor**.

and from [Temporal Juxtaposition](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=34472/temporal-juxtaposition):

> It would seem someone is attempting to affect a temporal shift by **sending items back into this timeline from your own timeline**.
>
> Technically that shouldn't be possible. But whoever this is found a way.

Two quests reference Outland specifically: [Settling Grievances](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=37128/settling-grievances)

> Hellmaw slew my brother in Outland... this is personal.

and [Completionism](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=38394/completionism)

> Interesting - the coins you've brought back from your Garrison are slightly different than the ones Nolan collected in Outland.

but neither of them specifically mention the timeline shifting.

Answer (score 2):

Upon satisfying the requirements to build your shipyard, Khadgar gives a quest entitled [The Final Assault](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=37841/the-final-assault); his dialogue for this quest includes the following lines:

> Our campaign in Draenor has taken an unexpected turn. With Gul'dan
>   assuming power over the Iron Horde, history is poised to repeat itself
>   - our world is in more peril than ever.

Together with Khadgar's quote from Jeremy's answer on this question, it's clear that this is Draenor from a different era, and history is in danger of repeating, spelling out the fact that this is a version of Draenor's past, before it becomes Outland, as has been established in the lore of previous *Warcraft* games and *The Burning Crusade*.

Answer (score 1):

[Quest link (spoiler)](http://wow.gamepedia.com/Quest:Tarnished_Bronze)

> You are Warchief no longer, Hellscream. You're free because I willed it. You live because I will it. You will join your father and rally the old orc clans because I will it!

Garrosh's father, Grommosh is known to be dead in the azerothian timeline.  He was killed in the fight with Mannoroth.

In the above quote, the speaker is talking about his intention to re-unite Garrosh with a not-dead draenor timeline Grommosh.